# Half circles collision

Tags: geometry, circles, computational-geometry

### How to find if 2 half circles collide ?

Hi, 
I have 2 half circles, circle1 and circle2, and I want to know if they collide.
Half circle details:

- Center - (x,y)
- Radius - r
- Heading angle - s - the direction in which the half circle is heading.

[An example of the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2ECU.png).
The upper example shows that the circles don't collide, and the lower example shows that the circles collide.

How do I calculate if the circles collide or not?